# Sharepoint 2010: Create a list which reflects results from another list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a share point site which collects user submitted information using a customized info path form connected to the list.  One of the major requirements for the site is users must be-able to submit information via the info path form, and to be-able to view the submissions to the list.  The trick is the list itself must be read-only.

In order to submit entries, contribute permissions must be applied, therefore I cannot apply read only permissions to the list as it will stop receiving submissions.  I had an idea to duplicate the list entries to another list, set the duplicate list to read only and display results from that list.  I cannot seem to create duplicate lists with SharePoint 2010, I can only create another list using the template layout from the current list.  Any ideas to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options,

Create a custom permission level that only allows the adding and viewing of items and add that to the list, this can be done through the UI and doesn't need any custom development but you should be able to get it working this way.

Create an event receiver that breaks the permissions inheritance and remove the contribute group from the item.

If you have a product like nitex you could do a workflow to do the above(I think)

Many Thanks

Truez